# TextBox: insert spaces for credit card number?

Tags: c#, wpf, regex, mvvm, credit-card

I have a credit card number text box which i want it to automatically insert spaces every 4 digits as the user types in the credit card number. how can i achieve that(in an elegant way if there is)? i am thinking if regular expressions can achieve it?

Comment: You don't need regular expressions to for a simple count.  Handle the KeyDown event and validate each key stroke.  Insert a space if needed.

Comment: If the numbers are separated if the norm not to have 4 separate text boxes with 4 digits in each?

Comment: Check this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1824550.aspx/1. You can achive this with javascript or jquery with keydown event

Answer (score 5):

you can try using the  `MaskedTextBox` from the

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox

to specify the format of the input

Answer (score 2):

Try using a MaskedTextBox from the WPF Toolkit.

```
<wpfx:MaskedTextBox Mask="0000 0000 0000 0000" />
```

[Tutorial Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-maskedtextbox-control/)